# WPF: Animating elements to new size on SizeChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-animation

I'm trying to animate buttons to grow when they appear using a style resource. To accomplish this I have used a uniformgrid with 1 row so the buttons will always be the same size and fill the space equally when they are not collapsed. When a button changes their visibility from collapsed to visible I want it to essentially grow to half the container size and the other button to shrink to half the container size (from full size).

Uniformgrid:

```
<UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Rows="1">
        <Button x:Uid="nextBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="backBtn" Content="{loc:Loc Key=STRING_BACK}" Style="{StaticResource NavBtn}" Click="backBtn_Click" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Button x:Uid="nextBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="nextBtn" Content="{loc:Loc Key=STRING_NEXT}" Style="{StaticResource NavBtn}" Click="nextBtn_Click"/>
    </UniformGrid>
```

The problem is that I do not want to hardcode either the button or uniformgrid's width. I read that WPF freezes resources, so I unfortunately can't use bindings to help here. Since uniformgrid regulates the size of my buttons, what I essentially want is just to animate my element when its size changes.

Is there any way to do this in WPF, or is there a better approach to this? It seemed possible because while debugging when SizeChanged is called, ActualWidth now has a value while Width is NaN.

Button style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NavBtn">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"></ScaleTransform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_2" Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Uid="ControlTemplate_1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Uid="Border_1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Uid="ContentPresenter_1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1" Duration="0:00:00.1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Your requirements seem contradictory. *"the buttons will always be the same size"* (hence UniformGrid) vs. *"grow to half the container size and the other button to shrink to half the container size"*.

Comment: You're right that does seem contradictory. However, when a button is collapsed essentially its width will be nonexistent or NaN. When it appears, I want it to essentially grow to whatever size uniformgrid will enforce.

Comment: A UIElement's Width is NaN unless you set it explicitly. Putting it in a UniformGrid doesn't change that. Anyway, you might animate a ScaleTransform in the Button's RenderTransform, since that doesn't affect the layout.

Comment: You can animate buttons from a smaller size to larger or whatever during visibility change with storyboards.  The buttons can also have a stretch value and automatically stick to the size of their container.  If you need more uniform scaling then look at using a ```ViewBox```.  I'm not sure what you're asking, the question is sort of confusing.  Maybe step by step the requirements here so that myself and possibly others can understand it better.

Comment: The description is a bit confusing but I think Clemens suggestion to animate scaletransform is what you want. IsVisibleChanged seems more appropriate, but it's not a routed event so you'd want a datatrigger <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsVisible}"